# Powerpoint VBA - Change Color Scheme

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to change color scheme of presentation to Office 2007-2010 though VBA code. How can I do that?

[image]

I tried something like below but doesn't seem to work.

```
ActivePresentation.ColorSchemes.Add
ActivePresentation.ColorSchemes(1).Colors(ppAccent1).RGB = RGB(0, 0, 1)
ActivePresentation.ColorSchemes(1).Colors(ppAccent1).RGB = RGB(0, 0, 2)
```

Comment: If the Theme Colors was exported to a *.xml* file, you can simply set (load) the presentation SlideMaster to it: `ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load "C:\Theme Colors\Office 2007 - 2010.xml"` Change the path to where you store the xml file.

Comment: You should be able to find the custom color xml file in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Colors`.

Comment: The question's been answered below, but it's worth pointing out that ColorSchemes are there only for backward compatibility with PPT versions before 2007. For PPT 2007 and onward, you want to work with ColorThemes.

Answer (score 2):

Changing color schemes in PowerPoint should be like this:

`ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent1) = RGB(1, 2, 3)`

There is a whole answer here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_winother/change-color-theme-using-vba-in-powerpoint/0efe38ad-36cb-4df7-b6e6-ed389c364f53

```
Sub mkThemeCols()
With ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Theme
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent1) = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent2) = RGB(0, 255, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent3) = RGB(0, 255, 255)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent4) = RGB(255, 255, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent5) = RGB(23, 255, 10)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent6) = RGB(23, 255, 100)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeDark1) = RGB(23, 0, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeDark2) = RGB(23, 23, 23)
.ThemeColorScheme.Save Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Colors\myNew Theme.xml"
End With
End Sub
```