# How to show theme color gallery in VBA PPT?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

May I know, how to show the theme color gallery shown below from PPT vba form, to change Font/Fill/Line colors? I need to call this theme color gallery to get input from users on my macro

[image: Theme color gallery]

[MS Word VBA: I need a color palette dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000721/ms-word-vba-i-need-a-color-palette-dialog-box)

[Show color picker for user to choose from in VBA powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514563/show-color-picker-for-user-to-choose-from-in-vba-powerpoint)

these articles shows how to pick RGB colors, but I need to use theme colors instead

Comment: @braX my requirement is not to change color scheme of the ppt. how to call theme color picker gallery

Comment: @BigBen sure, removed VSTO tag, thanks

Comment: yes, this screenshot is from the Home tab, dropdown. I need to call this theme color gallery to get input from user on my macro

Comment: You may find that you have no other choice than to recreate it then. I believe that is part of the ribbon and not something you can interact with like you want. I might be wrong, so you can wait to see if anyone else has another idea.

Comment: There are way to change the colors for the theme in VBA, but not using that interface.

Comment: I'm currently using a long shot method, would love to hear your suggestions to change theme colors. thanks @braX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403536/8422953

Comment: yes, I'm using a method similar to this, but looking to simplify by showing the theme color gallery instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239832/discussion-between-jegan-and-brax).