# Creating Slides: run time error '-2147024809 (80070057)' the specified value is out of range

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a slide deck in PowerPoint. I get

> run time error '-2147024809 (80070057)' the specified value is out of range

on line 5 for the color value.

```vb
Sub CreateNALS_Presentation()
    ' Set the color scheme for the presentation
    With ActivePresentation
        .SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeColorAccent1) = RGB(188, 190, 192)
        .SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeColorBackground1) = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeColorBackground2) = RGB(206, 52, 51)
    End With

    ' Add the title slide
    Dim TitleSlide As Slide
    Set TitleSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
    TitleSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NALS Membership Meeting"

    ' Add the remaining slides
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 42
        Dim NewSlide As Slide
        Set NewSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(i, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
        If i = 2 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Agenda"
        ElseIf i = 3 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NALS Board of Directors"
        ElseIf i = 4 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NALS Headquarters"
        ElseIf i = 5 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NALS Committee Chairs 2022-2023"
        ElseIf i = 6 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NALS Committee Chairs 2023-2024"
        ElseIf i = 7 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NALS Committees"
        ElseIf i = 8 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "2022 - 2023 Year in Review"
        ElseIf i = 9 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NALS 2023-2024 Strategic Plan"
        ElseIf i >= 10 And i <= 19 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Membership Growth Priority"
        ElseIf i = 20 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Brand Growth Priority"
        ElseIf i = 21 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NALS Chapter Event Promotion"
        ElseIf i = 22 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Brand Identity Priority"
        ElseIf i >= 23 And i <= 28 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Education Priority"
        ElseIf i = 29 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Financial Report"
        ElseIf i = 30 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Financial Report"
        ElseIf i = 31 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Revenue Sources"
        ElseIf i = 32 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Financial Priorities"
        ElseIf i >= 37 And i <= 39 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "2023 Elections"
        ElseIf i = 40 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Thank you!!"
        ElseIf i = 41 Then
            NewSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Q&A"
        End If
        
        Dim LogoPlaceholder As Shape
        Set LogoPlaceholder = NewSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:="[W:\SDrive\NALS\Marketing and Promotion\Branding\Logo Files - 2021 UPDATE\Main Logo\PNG\NALS-Logo-Circular-white.png]", _
          LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=100, Top:=400, Width:=100, Height:=100)
    Next i

End Sub
```

The debug in VBA usually points to line 5, `BackgroundColor1`.

I tried single values for the colors and ?RGB to find different values for the colors.

Comment: You are running this code in Access? How does Access know the 'ActivePresentation'? This code is not reproducible as presented. Compile error on `.ThemeColorScheme` - "Invalid use of property".

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402919/powerpoint-vba-change-color-scheme

Comment: Likely the value `msoThemeColorBackground1` is not valid in this context.

Comment: Nor is `msoThemeColorAccent1` but `msoThemeAccent1` is valid per intellisense tips. I tested in my procedure and this theme setting does not error but doesn't change anything either.

Comment: I used this to set a master theme: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Master.ApplyTheme. `.SlideMaster.ApplyTheme "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Templates\1033\Training.potx"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code *should* work, but hey, we're talking Microsoft. Instead, try:

```
.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeColorLight1) = RGB(255, 255, 255)
.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeColorLight2) = RGB(206, 52, 51)
```

Light1 and Background1 normally refer to the same thing.

Just a note about color themes, your second background color on the dark side, and that can create some odd effects in some table style and SmartArt variations.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The names you're looking for are Dark1 and Dark2, etc.  See screenshot.

Comment: A few dark-background themes use dark1 and dark2, so it's possible, but not common.